# New contacts created by my app appear only in the app - and not in the iOS contacts app

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

In my iOS app, I've created a few new contact using ABAddressBook API. I can see them in my app when scanning the contacts (persistently, even after closing my app and relaunching it).

However, I cannot see them in Apple's contacts App.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the groups enabled in the Contacts app (there's a Groups button in the navigation bar).

That being said, I recommend that you use a library to work with the address book: https://cocoapods.org/?q=Addressbook

I've used RHAddressBook in a previous app and was totally satisfied with it.

Comment: I do have all groups enabled. Still doesn't appear. :-(